# Trigger After Update

Tags: trigger

Need after update code for Trigger to update the account records.Following the Trigger

```
trigger OppOnAccount on Account(after insert,after update) 
{
    if(trigger.isinsert)
    {
        list<opportunity> Listopp  = new list<opportunity>();
        for(account acc:Trigger.new)
        {
            opportunity opp = new opportunity();
            opp.name = acc.name;
            opp.AccountId = acc.id;
            opp.StageName = 'Proposal';
            opp.CloseDate= system.today()+10;
            Listopp.add(opp);
        }
        insert Listopp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your problem with more details.

Comment: I agree with  @TusharSharma. Are you specifically trying to fire the code on after insert? In which case you could to `if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter)`?

Comment: nah, at a guess, I'm assuming he wants the trigger to UPDATE the relevant opportunity when the Account is updated... (a classic requirement and not too hard) but agree @Bonny needs to clarify this before I'm putting any thought into it!

Comment: Hello Simon.You got me would you please help me with code?

Comment: What you want to update @Bonny

Comment: Hello Tushar.I just need a code for this trigger in update scenario whenever the account is edit or update the related opportunity also updated.

Comment: @Bonny can you edit the original question saying what it is that you want to achieve and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 trigger OppOnAccount on Account(after insert,after update) 
    {
        if((Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter))
        {
            list<opportunity> Listopp  = new list<opportunity>();
            for(account acc:Trigger.new)
            {
                opportunity opp = new opportunity();
                opp.name = acc.name;
                opp.AccountId = acc.id;
                opp.StageName = 'Proposal';
                opp.CloseDate= system.today()+10;
                Listopp.add(opp);
            }
            insert Listopp;
        }
        if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter)
        {
            list<opportunity> Listopp  = new list<opportunity>();
             for(Account acc: [SElECT ID,  Name, (SELECT Name  FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE ID IN:  Trigger.new]) 
// Now you have all related Opp update them or perform any action you want to perform.
          {
           for(Opportunity opp: acc.Opportunities)
           {
                opp.name = acc.Name; //update other field here
                  Listopp.add(opp);
           }
         }
          update Listopp;
       }
    }
```

Use this sample code for reference. It will help you.

Comment: Hi Tushar.Thanks for answering but whenever i edit the account record its not reflect the changes in relevant opportunity record.Please help me with right piece of code.

Comment: @Bonny What field you want to update on Opportunity when you update Account . Please clear.

Comment: Like I Edit the name field in account record it should also update the account name field in opportunity.

Comment: @Bonny Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Tushar Your code is works for me.Really appreciate for your help.